# read txt file in c++ (chinese)

Tags: c++, locale

I'm trying to develop function that check whether chinese word which user enters is in the txt file or not. The following is the code. But it is not working. I want to know what the problem is. Help me please.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Chinese-simplified");
locale::global(locale("Chinese_China"));
SetConsoleOutputCP(936);
SetConsoleCP(936);

bool exist = FALSE;

cout << "\n\n <Find the keyword whether it is in that image or not> \n ";
cout << "Enter word to search for: ";
wstring search;
wcin >> search; //There is a problem to enter chinese.

wfstream file_text("./a.txt");
wstring line;
wstring::size_type pos;

while (getline(file_text, line))
{
    pos = line.find(search);
    if (pos != wstring::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
    {
        cout << "Found!" << endl;
        exist = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

when I use this code, The result is as follows.

```
const int oldMbcp = _getmbcp();
_setmbcp(936);
const std::locale locale("Chinese_China.936");
_setmbcp(oldMbcp);
```

[image]

Comment: In which way it _isn't working_? Elaborate please and post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `locale::global(locale("Chinese_China.936"));` or `locale::global(locale(""));`
And for LC_ALL `"chinese-simplified"` or `"chs"`

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in more details, please see [stod-does-not-work-correctly-with-boostlocale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744911/stod-does-not-work-correctly-with-boostlocale/34761910#34761910) for a more detailed description of how `locale` works,

In a nutshell the more interesting part for you:

1. `std::stream` (`stringstream`, `fstream`, `cin`, `cout`) has an inner locale-object, which matches the value of the global C++ locale **at the moment** of the creation of the stream object. As `std::in` is created long before your code in `main` is called, it has most probably the classical C locale, no matter what you do afterwards.
2. you can make sure, that a `std::stream` object has the desirable locale by invoking `std::stream::imbue(std::locale(your_favorit_locale))`.

I would like to add the following:

1. It is almost never a good idea to set the global locale - it might break other parts of the program or third part libraries - you never know.
2. `std::setlocale` and `locale::global` do slightly different things, but `locale::global` resets not only the global c++-locale but also the c-locale (which is also set by `std::setlocale`, not to be confused with the classical "C" locale), so you should call it in another order if you want to have c++ locale set to `Chinese_China` and C locale to `chinese-simplified`

First
    `locale::global(locale("Chinese_China"));`

And than
    `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Chinese-simplified");`

Comment: Hello, any idea on how I can change the inner locale-object of cout, stringstream etc.. after I have created these objects? How can any1 handle cases of multiple locales?

Comment: @BugShotGG you could use `std::cout.imbue(...)`

Answer (score 1):

If using [Vladislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35336071/341065) does not solve this, take a look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626263/341065) to [stl - Shift-JIS decoding fails using wifstrem in Visual C++ 2013 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618463/shift-jis-decoding-fails-using-wifstrem-in-visual-c-2013):

```
const int oldMbcp = _getmbcp();
_setmbcp(936);
const std::locale locale("Chinese_China.936");
_setmbcp(oldMbcp);
```

There appears to be [a bug in Visual Studio's implementation of locales](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1925650). See also [c++ - double byte character sequence conversion issue in Visual Studio 2015 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254089/double-byte-character-sequence-conversion-issue-in-visual-studio-2015).

Comment: It is not working, when I enter chinese word. Only when I enter English word and number, it is working.